# why I get a Run-time error 424 Object Required?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

```
Sub ChooseTestWords()

Dim i As Integer
Dim s As Shape
Dim wordsArray1(1 To 3) As Variant

' Assign the 3 values in the sheet4 to the array
 For i = 1 To 3
   wordsArray1(i) = Sheet4.Cells(i + 1, 2).Value
Next i

Sheet1.Shapes("TestWordsBox").TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = wordsArray1(1).Value

End Sub
```

I get an

> object Required Error

at

```
Sheet1.Shapes("TestWordsBox").TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = wordsArray1(1).Value
```

May I know Why the error? I'm simply assigning the value of the array to the text of the shape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An array doesn't have a `.Value`. Change

```
Sheet1.Shapes("TestWordsBox").TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = wordsArray1(1).Value
```

to

```
Sheet1.Shapes("TestWordsBox").TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = wordsArray1(1)
```

Comment: wow.. it worked.  since, i'm new i want to know why.  in VBA value is a default property right. whether you mention it or not.

example x = range("A1").value is sames as x = Range("A1")..